# Flatten a track's BPM

Tags: music

I'm looking for a software that can flatten a track's BPM, i.e. e.g. if the track begins at 120 BPM, reaches 122 BPM at the middle, and eventually slows down to 118 BPM, I would like the track to converted into a track with the same BPM throughout the track.

If possible:

- Windows (but Linux, Mac OS X are OK too)
- free
- support MP3
- can set which BPM I want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) to do this sort of processing, in fact there are a number of tools in it for this - possibly your best bet is the [Time Tracks Tool](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/time_tracks.html).

Audacity is:

- Cross Platform - including **Windows**
- **Free**
- Supports multiple codecs and file types including WAV, AIFF, FLAC, MP2, **MP3** & Ogg Vorbis
- Allows you to vary the BPM of any given section.

Comment: Thanks but it seems like I have to manually do it, right?

Comment: If you think that it would be a commonly needed feature you could put it in as a suggestion http://audacity.sourceforge.net/contact/#feedback - I don't know the code base but given there is already a beat detection feature and the various tempo adjustments I would think that 85% of it is already there.